# Getting error (java: illegal start of expression) cause of +,-,*,/?

Tags: java

**Hello! I started learning programming and started with a weird way of a calculator (I know its weird how I made it). But at this little Code I got a Problem with java: illegal start of expression because of "if (numberTest.equals(+))" but i get an error too when i make "if (numberTest == /)". Any help to solve this Problem because i didnt find anything and dont know what to search? (: Have a nice day guys! Stay safe**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class learningCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      

        System.out.println("Bitte schreiben sie + für eine Plus Rechnung");
        System.out.println("Bitte schreiben sie * für eine Mal Rechnung");
        System.out.println("Bitte schreiben sie / für eine Geteilt Rechnung");
        System.out.println("Bitte shchreiben sie - für eine Minus Rechnung");

        String numberTest = scan.nextLine();



        if (numberTest.equals(+)) {
            String questionOne = "Bitte gebe deine erste Zahl ein: ";
            System.out.println(questionOne);
            int number1 = scan.nextInt();
            String questionTwo = "Bitte gebe deine zweite Zahl ein: ";
           `enter code here` System.out.println(questionTwo);
            int number2 = scan.nextInt();
            int finalResult = number1 + number2;

            String Answer = "Deine Zahl ist: ";

            System.out.println(Answer  + finalResult );

            scan.close();
        }
        else {
            if (numberTest.equals(*)) {
                String questionTwo = "Bitte gebe deine erste Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionTwo);
                int number1 = scan.nextInt();
                String questionThree = "Bitte gebe deine zweite Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionThree);
                int number2 = scan.nextInt();
                int finalResult = number1 * number2;

                String Answer = "Deine Zahl ist: ";

                System.out.println(Answer  + finalResult );

                scan.close();
            }
            if (numberTest == /) {
                String questionThree = "Bitte gebe deine erste Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionThree);
                int number1 = scan.nextInt();
                String questionFour = "Bitte gebe deine zweite Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionFour);
                int number2 = scan.nextInt();
                int finalResult = number1 / number2;

                String Answer = "Deine Zahl ist: ";

                System.out.println(Answer  + finalResult );

                scan.close();
            }
            if (numberTest == /) {
                String questionFive = "Bitte gebe deine erste Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionFive);
                int number1 = scan.nextInt();
                String questionSix = "Bitte gebe deine zweite Zahl ein: ";
                System.out.println(questionSix);
                int number2 = scan.nextInt();
                int finalResult = number1 - number2;

                String Answer = "Deine Ergebnis ist: ";

                System.out.println(Answer  + finalResult );

                scan.close();
            }

        }


    }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your sign with quotes...

```
if(numberTest.equals("+")){
   //your code
}
```